# How do I create an atlas with multiple maps for each coverage layer with QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am doing a NSW transport map that would like to segregate using Local Government Areas (LGAs). However, I specified that each map should be in the same scale, hence I would like to have many "same-scale" submaps per LGA maps.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: If you print your submaps for each LGA with the Print Composer Atlas functionality you can fix (lock) the scale for all submaps. You will have to handle each LGA manually when printing submaps. There is no databinding on mapscale in Atlas.

Comment: In one atlas coverage run there can only be on coverage layer. Can't see how you could loop the coverage without doing som programming.

Comment: @Jakob If there is no such solution, maybe you can answer below that no such solution exists. Otherwise, it would be helpful to provide some hint on the programming for such solution. Haven't said that, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I am out for field work the next days, so have no time for a programming solution. I've leave the question a few days to see if someone smarter than me comes along.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to split your coverage layer up into sublayers, where each LGA is split into regions corresponding to each page in the atlas.

Comment: I appreciate your idea and may I ask of the function or plugin in QGIS to implement such idea? However, I have some kind of ideas but just for completeness.